# Access value by using a key in an array

Tags: arrays, woocommerce

I am trying to access the values inside the array.

> Sample Array $gateways

```
[cheque] => WC_Gateway_Cheque Object
        (
            [order_button_text] => 
            [enabled] => yes
            [title] => Check payments
            [description] => Please send a check to Store Name, Store Street, Store Town, Store State / County, Store Postcode.
            [chosen] => 
      )

foreach($gateways as $key=>$value){
            if($key->title == 'xyz'){
                unset($gateways[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

How can I access the [title] value inside the array?

I tried **$key->title**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $value->title instead of $key->title, your code would execute perfectly then. As $key indicates the key for that particular gateway and $values contains the whole object array.